# .NET ICollection Class Basics

Tags: c#, icollection

All, I have an application that needs to attach and detach multiple SQL databases regularly. I want to create a class that holds all of these databases as a collection that can be iterated over. To do this I am inheriting from `ICollection`, but there is some thinkg I am not understanding:

```
class SqlDataBases : ICollection<SqlDb>
{
    private List<SqlDb> dbColl;

    public SqlDataBases()
    {
        dbColl = new List<SqlDb>();
    }

    // Add an index to the collection.
    public SqlDb this[int _nIndex]
    {
        get { return (SqlDb)dbColl[_nIndex]; }
        set { dbColl[_nIndex] = value; }
    }

    // et al.
}

public class DbEnumerator : IEnumerator<SqlDb>
{
    // ...
}

class SqlDb
{
    private string strMdfFullPath;
    private string strLdfFullPath;
    private bool bIsAttached;

    public SqlDb(string _strMdfFullPath, string _strLdfFullPath, bool _bIsAttached)
    {
        this.strMdfFullPath = _strMdfFullPath;
        this.strLdfFullPath = _strLdfFullPath;
        this.bIsAttached = _bIsAttached;
    }
}
```

My question is "why inherit from `ICollection` at all, when you have to add methods such as 'Add', 'Contains' etc. yourself? Or do you have to do this yourself as suggested in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx)? I have been reading "C# in a Nutshell" and this question is something that stands out unaddressed in this great book.

I apologise, I know I am missing something here...

Comment: My thought is the same; why don't you just use a `List<SqlDb>` where needed? It has the features you try to implement as far as I can see.

Comment: @Killercam, One comment below suggests using a Dictionary<>. Unless you want to "Find" your connection by name over and over, a Dictionary<> would be better because you can specify a key like the database name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is "why inherit from ICollection at all, when you have to add methods such as 'Add', 'Contains' etc. yourself?

`ICollection<T>` is an *interface* - it just specifies the members that you have to implement. If you want to derive from something which already *has* an implementation, look at [`Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx). You would implement the interface yourself if you wanted to create your own collection data structure with its own special characteristics - I doubt that you want to do that.

To be honest, it's not clear why you want your own class here at all - why not just use `List<SqlDb>` in the client code directly?

Comment: Thanks Jon, that has sorted out my stupidity. And you are right, I only need a `List<SqlDb>` here - but I have not created my own collection class before and fancied doing it, but it is foolish. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought about using `List<SqlDb>` directly?

It's not obvious to me what you hope to gain by the SqlDataBases class.

If you can't use `List<SqlDb>` directly, think about inheriting from `List<SqlDb>` rather than `ICollection<SqlDb>`.

Comment: I'd put it into dictionary though... but the reasons for this are yet unknown

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces are only skeletons. They aren't containing any logic, they are containing only the signatures of all method, property etc.

[Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The reason to inherit from ICollection<> is to create your own custom collection type.  Then, anywhere a method has an input variable of ICollection<>, because you inherited from ICollection<>, your new custom collection type can be passed in.

In your case, you could simply use List<> until you find a need to create a custom collection.

Answer (score 1):

Answering "why inherit from ICollection at all, when you have to add methods such as 'Add'":

you don't need to inherit ICollection if you don't need/want to have Add/Next etc.